# Animation of led strip with ESP32 does not work when WiFi is in use

Tags: c++, interrupt, esp32, led-strip

I am using the ESP32 for a simple project. I know how to animate an led strip using atmega328p with arduino but when I animate it on the ESP32 it does not work that great. It will be nice if I can use the same ESP32 to run my entire project without having to include another MCU. **Has someone managed to be able to animate an led strip meanwhile using wifi on the ESP32** ?

This is the code I use to animate an LED stip meanwhile using wifi. I wrote this code myself so maybe I am doing something wrong. It works better than any of the libraries I have found online. The library that works best is [esp32WS2811-master](https://github.com/bertmelis/esp32WS2811). But still this code works better than that library in my case.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "WiFi.h"
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

// we will runt the task that animates led strip on a separate core of arduino
TaskHandle_t Task1;

// where led pin is connected and number of leds to animate
#define PIN 32
#define NUM_LEDS 80

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUM_LEDS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

// mutex that helps enter critical sections meanwhile we animate led strip
portMUX_TYPE mux = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;


// it will run on core 0 of esp32. Responsible for animating led strip.
void loop2(void *parameter)
{
   uint32_t _color = strip.Color(0, 0, 0);

   for (;;) // infinite loop
   {
      _color = strip.Color(0, 0, 255);

      // animation 1
      for (uint16_t i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++)
      {                                  
         strip.setPixelColor(i, _color); 

         //portDISABLE_INTERRUPTS();      // arternative to portENTER_CRITICAL
         portENTER_CRITICAL(&mux);        /* start critical section */

         strip.show();

         //portENABLE_INTERRUPTS();       // alternative to portEXIT_CRITICAL
         portEXIT_CRITICAL(&mux);         /* end critical section */

         vTaskDelay(15);                  // one tick delay (15ms) in between reads for stability
      }

     
      // animation 2
      _color = strip.Color(0, 255, 0);
      for (uint16_t i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++)
      {                                   
         strip.setPixelColor(i, _color);  

         //portDISABLE_INTERRUPTS();      // arternative to portENTER_CRITICAL
         portENTER_CRITICAL(&mux);        /* start critical section */

         strip.show();

         //portENABLE_INTERRUPTS();       // alternative to portEXIT_CRITICAL
         portEXIT_CRITICAL(&mux);         /* end critical section */

         vTaskDelay(15);                  // one tick delay (15ms) in between reads for stability
      }
   }
}

void setup()
{    
   Serial.begin(115200);

   // disabling wifi helps but we need it
   // WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);

   // init led strip
   strip.begin();
   strip.setBrightness(4);
   strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'

   // create a task that runs on core 0 of esp32
   xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
       loop2,
       "Task_1",
       1000,
       NULL,
       2, // priority of 0 is the lowest.
       &Task1,
       0 // use core 0. Core 1 is the default core
   );

   // continue running code on default core 1 of esp32

   // Set WiFi to station mode and disconnect from an AP if it was previously connected
   WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
   WiFi.disconnect();
   
   Serial.println("Setup done");
}

// on main loop scan network just to show how led strip does not work great when wifi is in use
// This code I copied and pasted from the WiFi examples of the esp32
void loop()
{
   Serial.println("scan start");

   // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
   int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
   Serial.println("scan done");
   if (n == 0)
   {
      Serial.println("no networks found");
   }
   else
   {
      Serial.print(n);
      Serial.println(" networks found");
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      {
         // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
         Serial.print(i + 1);
         Serial.print(": ");
         Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));
         Serial.print(" (");
         Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(i));
         Serial.print(")");
         Serial.println((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == WIFI_AUTH_OPEN) ? " " : "*");
         delay(10);
      }
   }
   Serial.println("");           

   // wait 5 seconds for next network scan
   auto end = millis() + (unsigned long)5000;
   while(millis() < end)  {
      vTaskDelay(1);
   }

}
```

When I run this code the first led flickers. The other LEDs animate great 99.99% of the time. When I disable WiFi this code works great. I still need `portENTER_CRITICAL(&mux);` or `portDISABLE_INTERRUPTS();` for it to work even if I disable WiFi. Has anyone managed to be able to animate an led-strip with the ESP-32 successfully meanwhile using WiFi?

If I am required to use a separate micro controller which one do you guys recommend? The [ATtiny85](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATtiny85)?

Comment: it's not the wifi, it's your delay calls and while statements that are stopping the show.

Comment: The delay is part of the animation. If I disable the wifi the animation works great @dandavis. I need to animate one led every 15 milliseconds.

Comment: well, I know that i can push rgb values over wifi to an esp32 at 30FPS on a 64 pixel strip. If wifi blocked this would look really jerky, but it doesn't, except for occasional hiccups which fix themselves. I didn't even mess with interrupts or explicit flow control. Make your animation routine async (think blink w/o delay) to allow more than one thing at once to happen. For me, this required rewriting the adafruit lib to move the loops into stand-alone callable functions that did a single iteration worth of work at the right time, as determined by the loop()'s logic and millis().

Comment: Doesn't all the WiFi management software run on core 0? If you run on core 1 does it improve?

Comment: @danvis are you using an addressable led strip?  are you animating your LED by changing the color of one led at a time? If I use a none addressable led strip it works.

Comment: @Majenko if I use core 1 it works better. I just get some flickering once every 5 seconds. But the LEDs animate great its just the flickering that I have to somehow figure out how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the FastLed library and it works now. For some reason the adafruit library only works when I am not using the WiFi. This code works:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <FastLED.h>
#include "WiFi.h"

// we will runt the task that animates led strip on a separate core of arduino
TaskHandle_t Task1;

#define LED_PIN 32
#define NUM_LEDS 108
#define BRIGHTNESS 10
#define LED_TYPE WS2811
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

#define UPDATES_PER_SECOND 100



// scan the network every 5 seconds 
void loop2(void *parameter)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        Serial.println("scan start");

        // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
        int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
        Serial.println("scan done");
        if (n == 0)
        {
            Serial.println("no networks found");
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.print(n);
            Serial.println(" networks found");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
                Serial.print(i + 1);
                Serial.print(": ");
                Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));
                Serial.print(" (");
                Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(i));
                Serial.print(")");
                Serial.println((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == WIFI_AUTH_OPEN) ? " " : "*");
                delay(10);
            }
        }
        Serial.println("");

        vTaskDelay(5000);
    }
}



void setup()
{

    Serial.begin(115200);

    delay(1000); // power-up safety delay
    FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, LED_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
    FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);


    // Set WiFi to station mode and disconnect from an AP if it was previously connected
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.disconnect();

    // create a task that runs on core 0 of esp32
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        loop2,
        "Task_1",
        1000,
        NULL,
        2, // priority of 0 is the lowest.
        &Task1,
        1 // use core 0. Core 1 is the default core
    );

    Serial.println("Setup done");
}


void loop()
{

    // red
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
    {
        leds[i] = 0xFF0000;
        FastLED.show();
        FastLED.delay(25);
    }

    // green
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
    {
        leds[i] = 0x00FF00;
        FastLED.show();
        FastLED.delay(25);
    }

    // blue
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
    {
        leds[i] = 0x0000FF;
        FastLED.show();
        FastLED.delay(25);
    }

    // rgb red green blue

    //ChangePalettePeriodically();
    //FillLEDsFromPaletteColors( startIndex);
}
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer so it doesn't pop up over and over again